# Deal with renamed videos in youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I currently have `youtube-dl` set up to download new videos from my favorite YouTubers automatically. It stores each video in `author/yyyymmdd-author-videotitle.ext`, and is set to not overwrite.

This works fairly well, with a good balance between readability and sortability. However, if the title of the video is changed, there's nothing telling `youtube-dl` that it's already downloaded.

Is there a solution to this that lets me keep the title intact?
The only thing I've thought of is to name files as `yyyymmdd-videoid.ext`, and keep an EXTM3U playlist with video titles. (EXTM3U playlist let you override titles.)

Comment: I don't have a solution, but a hint: what about `md5`ing (or, if you insist, applying the good ol' `crc32` on) the video file and doing a byte-wise file comparison? This would, however, have to be programmed *into* `youtube-dl` because once it has finished doing its work, there is no "post-operation" you can do on it. (Because you want to **prevent** the tool from downloading in the first place if the video already exists!)

Comment: That seems like a good idea, but how would I implement that with my current setup? I just have `youtube-dl -w https://youtube.com/someplaylist`.

Comment: `youtube-dl` is handling playlist parsing, and downloads.

Comment: I'd say you can't. You **must** find a way to tell `youtube-dl` to *skip* downloading when files are equal byte-wise. And this can only be done in code (i. e. by expanding it (-->feature request??)), because the current version of the script *will* already have downloaded the video when you will be returned to your `bash` prompt again - no matter if already there or not.--- In comparison, think of an observer/intercepting mechanism in web servers that can hook in *before* any JavaScript is ever loaded. The same thing you need to do here *before* `youtube-dl` attempts to download from YT.

Comment: Well actually, I think I could set up a script to have `youtube-dl` download the videos to `artist/.tmp/vid_id.ext`, test the checksum against a file of all video checksums, and if it matches, delete it. If not, move it to the correct directory.

Comment: Well, I should've worded better. My intention is to not have duplicates. I'm not worried about having to download.

Comment: Ah, OK. So this'd work, even though it seemed against your original intention, hence I chose not to mention it. :) Anyways, it's true: from user's (or client's side), the only way you can do is live with the duplicate *already downloaded* (as you can't prevent it from happening, as I explained above) and *afterwards* doing your deletion operations on it if need be.

Comment: Another (hacky) way would be to have the `.tmp` directory filled with symlinks just called `video_id`, which would be symlinks to the actual files, with `youtube-dl` set to download in the same manner (`.tmp/video_id`). With `youtube-dl`'s no-overwrite option (`-w`), it would see these as downloaded files and not download the video in the first place. Then a script would get all non-symlink files in the directory, rename them accordingly, and place them in the correct directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `--download-archive FILENAME`. The md5-based solution won't work since YouTube [adds unique data to each video](https://superuser.com/questions/503868/how-i-can-remove-all-google-data-from-youtube-video-downloads) so that md5 fluctuates until you remove this data yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. Well, in case that data is always added at the same (relative) offset (e. g. 1024 bytes before the end of the video, or even at invariable starting and ending offsets), even this would be possible to handle. But I'd have to do a more thorough test to be sure. :)